# trouble using replaceregexp when replacing string DIR location

Tags: ant

I am having trouble in doing this.
there is 1 batch file with this line:

**set TEST_DIR=C:\temp\dir1**

I just want to set some new value to TEST_DIR

But, when I use  in my ant script, it escapes forward slashes and gives this result:

**set TEST_DIR=C:homedir2**

Instead, I want to give it:

**set TEST_DIR=C:\home\dir2**

I am using this command:

```
<replaceregexp file="${MT_BATCH_FILE_LOCATION}\myfile.bat" match="TEST_DIR=C:\\temp\\dir1" replace="TEST_DIR=C:\home\dir2" byline="true" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found another simple solution use **replace** instead of **replaceregexp**.

```
<replace file="${MT_BATCH_FILE_LOCATION}\myfile.bat"
                            token='TEST_DIR=C:\temp\dir1'
                    value='TEST_DIR=${new_loc}\home\dir2' />
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the result you want by using this replace pattern:

```
 replace="TEST_DIR=C:\\\\home\\\\dir2"
```

The reason is that you must escape the backslash once for the regex and once for Java - backslash is an escape character in both those contexts.

In answer to your subsequent questions in comments...

1. I expect the answer will be the same. You will need to double-escape the backslash in the value of `${new_loc}`, i.e. use `C:\\\\my_projcode` not `C:\my_projcode`.
2. If new_loc is coming in as an environment variable, you could use the [propertyregex task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) from ant-contrib to escape backslashes in the value:

   ```
   <project default="test">

     <!-- import ant-contrib --> 
     <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
       <classpath>
         <pathelement location="C:/lib/ant-contrib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
       </classpath>
     </taskdef>

     <target name="test">

       <!-- load environment variables -->
       <property environment="env"/>

       <!-- escape backslashes in new_loc -->
       <propertyregex property="loc" input="${env.new_loc}" regexp="\\" replace="\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" />

       <echo message="env.new_loc: ${env.new_loc}"/>
       <echo message="loc: ${loc}"/>

       <!-- do the replace --> 
       <replaceregexp file="test.bat" match="TEST_DIR=C:\\temp\\dir1" replace="TEST_DIR=${loc}\\\\home\\\\dir2" byline="true" />

     </target>
   ```

Output:

```
c:\tmp\ant>set new_loc=c:\foo\bar

c:\tmp\ant>ant
Buildfile: c:\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
     [echo] new_loc: c:\foo\bar
     [echo] env.new_loc: c:\foo\bar
     [echo] loc: c:\\\\foo\\\\bar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

c:\tmp\ant>type test.bat
set TEST_DIR=c:\foo\bar\home\dir2
```

Comment: hey it worked well..but my problem got resolved partially....actually in original built i have one variable also which i wand to add to my new location... here is the code i am using..

Comment: <replaceregexp file="${MT_BATCH_FILE_LOCATION}\myfile.bat" match="TEST_DIR=C:\\temp\\dir1" replace="TEST_DIR=${new_loc}\\\\home\\\\dir2" byline="true" />

Comment: and its giving result... TEST_DIR=C:my_projcode\home\dir2  between C: and my_projcode the slash seems to be still missing..

Comment: hey that is the problem; here the variable is taking value from environment i cant edit on my own..

Comment: is there any way to put this variable to constant string and then append it to my location

Comment: GRT ..awesome, it worked well ..now i ll try similar approach for editing shell file with forward slashes and double quotes TEST_DIR="/disk1/dir1" ...i hope this approach will work well....thanks a lot